# How to find distance between two longitude location?

Tags: android

I want your help to calculate the distance b/t two longitudes. Can anybody tell me how to find the distance? I am new on Android studio. I want to find the distance in my app. Destination address in defined by `mlat` and `mlong` and current address is calculated through GPS whose value goes in longitude and latitude.

My code is:

```
    double mlat =30.726030;
    double mlong=76.759268;
    imgButton1 =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    mgButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
                Location gpsLocation = appLocationService.getLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                if (gpsLocation != null) {
                     double latitude = gpsLocation.getLatitude();
                     double longitude = gpsLocation.getLongitude();    
                     String result = "Latitude: " + gpsLocation.getLatitude() +
                                    " Longitude: " + gpsLocation.getLongitude();
                     tvAddress.setText(result);
                } else {
                     showSettingsAlert();
                }
          }
   });
```

Tell me how to find the distance between two longitudes and latitudes.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `distanceBetween` method to calculate distance:

```
Location.distanceBetween(double startLatitude, double startLongitude, double endLatitude, double endLongitude, float[] results)
```